# Vue reads v-bind:class before computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use `v-for` to display a list of images in my container. After this, I calculate the start and end positions of these images using `$refs` in a computed property.

The problem is that I want to use `v-bind:class=""` to animate them, but Vue reads this before the computed property is created (my guess).

```
<img ref="imageAnimate" class="image-parts"
     v-for="(images, i) in finalImages"
     :src="images.full_image_url"
     :class="{animated: scroll >=animateHooks[i].animated}">

animateHooks() {
  let hooks = [];
  for (i=0; i < this.$refs.imageAnimate.length; i++) {
    let img = {
      start: this.$refs.imageAnimate[i].offsetTop,
      end: this.$refs.imageAnimate[i].offsetTop + this.$refs.imageAnimate[i].offsetHeight,
      animated: false
    };
    hooks.push(img);
  }
  return hooks;
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that computed properties are calculated after the render cycle, but rather that you are using a computed property that tries to find an element that has not yet been rendered.

On the first render cycle, the component has not been rendered yet. It will loop through `finalImages` and try to set the class based on your computed property. Since nothing has been rendered yet, `this.$refs` is empty. Trying to get the length of that will result in "Cannot get property length of undefined". One solution would be to not loop through the refs, but instead loop through `finalImages` to create your computed property. I am not 100% sure if it will recalculate the computed property based on `this.$refs` though, but there is only one way to figure that out.

```
animateHooks() {
  const refs = this.$refs.imageAnimate;

  return this.finalImages.map((image, index) => {
    const img = {
      start: refs ? refs[i].offsetTop : 0,
      end: refs ? (refs.offsetTop + refs[i].offsetHeight) : 0,
      animated: false
    };
    return img;
  });
}
```

You would be able to access the `$refs` one tick after the initial render (e.g. inside a `this.$nextTick(() => { ... });`), but this is of no use to you in a computed property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been thinking the wrong direction the whole way. Now i actualy uderstand where mistake was made. Big thanks!